# Google alert on native search page: The site may be compromised

Tags: google-search

While searching for our company name, we get (in the native results page) a message that claims:
[image]

Webmaster tools does not tell me much about this, and so does the server log.

- I don't get that message searching with Bing

Where should I check to remove the offending code (if at all there is one - and it's not a false-positive by google)

Further investigations, shows that none of the free online scanning tools, show my site as infected (even the google resutls say it's clean) but still I get this alert

http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/www.optitex.com   - shows that the site is clean, even by Google engine.

http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=optitex.com

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

If I use the WMT Fetch as Google - I get a thumbnail of the page - and that still shows ads for drugs (so help me GoD)

[image]

so: where is this coming from?
how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you click on the link [This site may be compromised](http://support.google.com/websearch/answer/190597?hl=en&?sa=X&ei=lCFkUZqCHsXI4AODtoHAAw&ved=0CDsQpwgwAA)? That points you to an an [instructions](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=163634) page within the Webmaster Tools with information on what you can/should do.

Comment: Thanks, I have - but when asked to go to the Malware: request a review -  I get a message: Google has not detected any malware on this site.  so From googles POV my site is clean, but I still get the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [page linked by Al Everett](http://support.google.com/websearch/answer/190597?hl=en) says (**emphasis** mine):

> "To be clear, when our malware detection system classifies a site as potentially hosting malware, we show a **"This site may harm your computer"** message. When we believe a site may be hacked or compromised but have not detected malware, we display **"This site may be compromised"** as an alert."

So the bad news is, your site has almost certainly been hacked.  The good news is that it doesn't (so far) appear to be actively distributing malware to your visitors, but simply feeding your pagerank to spam domains.

The reason you don't see anything wrong when you visit the site is almost certainly that the malicious code injected into your site is set to [only run when visited from Google's IP addresses](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355).  (It could also be checking the User-Agent string, but in that case you should be able to trigger it by changing your browser's User-Agent string manually to match Googlebot's; I just tried that myself, and got nothing suspicious back.)  That's why the spam only shows up in Google's search results and through "fetch as Googlebot".

To get rid of it, you'll want to both remove the existing infection (preferably by restoring to a known-to-be-good backup, to make sure no backdoors are left in place) and update your software to keep it from happening again.  (The most common way such spam infections happen is through known vulnerabilities in old versions of CMSes or other widely used software.)  For details, see e.g. [these instructions from Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2600721) or these more general tips from [StopBadware](https://www.stopbadware.org/common-hacks).